# adding a query to an axios get request

Tags: vuejs2, axios

I am trying to restrict what gets returned by my axios get request.

I have a firebase backend and in my data i have a field called case_name, I have added a few records with the name Test and thought i could run the following in a get request to restrict my results to just those where case_name is equal to test, but it still returns all records

```
loadCase ({ commit, context }) {
      return axios.get('http', {
        params: {
          case_name: 'Test'
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        const convertcase = []
        for (const key in res.data) {
          convertcase.push({ ...res.data[key], id: key })
        }
        commit('listcase', convertcase)
      })
      .catch(e => context.error(e));
    },
```

Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong please as cant find anything to help me at the moment

my returned object is

```
data: {…}
​​
"-LFXvk9yY5c-O8yIdf8k": Object { case_name: "Test", case_status: "live", case_summary: "This is some summary content", … }
​​
"-LFXwmv6eHqZs8jndNay": Object { case_name: "case 2", case_status: "live", case_summary: "dasdasdasdasd\nasd\ndasd\na\nsdasdasd", … }
​​
"-LFc2t9V7LVqnLAlIjoU": Object { case_name: "Test", case_status: "live", case_summary: "this is just another summary", … }
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like backend interface problem, your params is send success

Comment: Is it something odd around how firebase works? from what I have read https://pathtofirebase/cases.json?case_name=Test should work but doesnt, anyone familiar with firebase can explain why this is not the case?

Comment: I ve added the object i get returned from firebase to the question incase anyone can see what I'm doing wrong